# Add text between vars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have :

```
$("#result").html('your choice: '+state);
```

Which returns : your choice: Queensland

I can do this:

```
$("#result").html('your choice: '+state +result);
```

Which returns : your choice: QueenslandBrisbane

What I want to do is add Spacing between ( and span classes to either of the elements so I get )

your choice: **Queensland** > **Brisbane**

With something like < span class="strongblue">Queensland< /span> etc

Issue I seem to be having is adding the > between +state and +result.

Cheers

Comment: @422, you should probably take some time and learn the basics of JS. I recommend [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com)

Comment: I suppose you can fit air conditioners Matti ?

Comment: @422: Nope, I'd probably get an expert to do that.

Comment: Exactly. Stop trolling and allow ppl like me the freedom to ask questions that others more learned can assist with, it may well help someone else in the future.

Comment: @422: I meant I'd get an expert as in I'd pay somebody who can do it to do it instead of going online and going "hey can somebody help me fit an air conditioner, I've never done it before and I have no idea how"

Comment: Well I am a refrigeration mechanic, and whilst I dont assume to know everything, I am keen to learn. But I guess thats beyond your scope of reason dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#result").html("your choice: <span>" 
                 + state 
                 + "</span><span>&gt</span><span>" 
                 + result 
                 + "</span>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you do `$("#result").html('your choice: ' + state + ' &gt; ' + result);` ?

Comment: ahhh it was the secondary + after state I was missing. I had tried your method, but didnt add + state + i did + state

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#result").html('your choice: '+state + ' &gt; ' +result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another string literal in:

```
$("#result").html('your choice: ' + state ' &gt; ' + result);
```

If you want them in spans, something like

```
$("#result").html('your choice: <span>' + state + '</span> &gt; <span>' + result + '</span>');
```